# PHP - Azure mySQL in-app Changed Ports Randomly

Tags: php, mysql, azure

**Background:** I have a PHP CMS running on Azure Web App with MySQL in-app. It has been running fine for a few months, all of a sudden started getting SQL error "An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions" I dug around the the CMS and compared the connection string provided by Azure and found out that the port for Azures In-App MySQL had changed to a new port for no reason i am aware of. Quickly updated it and it is working now. But the issue is, i had to find out the hard way from a customer complaining about it.

**Question:** Why did the port change and will it do this again? How do i stop it from changing in the future or specify explicitly which port I want it to use going forward?

*Thanks*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been answered by @Suwatch [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/4c582216-bc1b-48b0-b80b-87ae540c3d05/php-azure-mysql-inapp-changed-ports-randomly), which says:

> A VM can host multiple WebApps; hence multiple in-app MySQL processes.
>   When we start MySql process, we attempt to use the same port as
>   before. However, it may be taken by other service or other in-app
>   MySQL. As a result, the port may change. In addition, web app can be
>   moved from one VM to another and the set of available ports will be
>   different.
>
> In order to write the stable client app, do make sure you read the
>   connection info from env variable. See [this](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/MySQL-in-app-%28preview%29#where-can-i-find-mysql-credentials-connection-string) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did to solve mine:  My app is an ASP Core WebAPI

```
string connection = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MYSQLCONNSTR_localdb");
var dbhost = Regex.Match(connection, @"Data Source=(.+?);").Groups[1].Value;
var server = dbhost.Split(':')[0].ToString();
var port = dbhost.Split(':')[1].ToString();
var dbname = Regex.Match(connection, @"Database=(.+?);").Groups[1].Value;
var dbusername = Regex.Match(connection, @"User Id=(.+?);").Groups[1].Value;
var dbpassword = Regex.Match(connection, @"Password=(.+?)$").Groups[1].Value;

string connectionString2 = $@"server={server};userid={dbusername};password={dbpassword};database={dbname};port={port};pooling = false; convert zero datetime=True;";
```