# Could not find Host of Azure In App SQL Database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I've created a MySQL In App database for my Azure App, and got the connection string for it. This string is injected into the *application.json*, and then used to create the actual connection:

```
WebApplicationBuilder builder = // get it somewhere
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(options => options.UseMySQL(connectionString));
```

Only... no connection string works. The one with the port (`Database=localdb;Data Source=127.0.0.1:53844;User Id=azure;Password=password`) throws:

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (11001): No such host is known.

And the one without the port (`Database=localdb;Data Source=127.0.0.1;User Id=azure;Password=password`) throws:

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10013): An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48113399/how-to-connect-to-the-azure-mysql-in-app-localdb-using-c-sharp) sugested another connection string (`Server=127.0.0.1; Port=53844; Database=localdb; Uid=azure; Pwd=password`), which weirdly enough also throws this exception, even though the port is defined:

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10013): An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.

And [the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework-core.html) suggests yet another string (`server=localhost;database=localdb;user=azure;password=password`) which again throws one of the two exceptions depending on if the port is present.

Connecting via the browser works fine, so I can confirm port, username and password work normally.

Just to be sure, I tried "localhost" as the host, too. Same results.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a mix out of all these connection strings:

```
server=localhost;port=53844;database=localdb;user=azure;password=password
```

(Port and server separated, but both present.)

Works for me right now.